# What is the intersection of a plane and a sphere? Is it necessarily a circle? Can it be an ellipse?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stereographic-projections

[A First Course in Complex Analysis by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, and Lucas Sabalka](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html) Exer 3.27,Exer 3.28

> (Exer 3.27) Consider the plane $H$ determined by the equation $x + y -z = 0$. What is a [unit normal vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878090) to $H$? Compute the image of $E:=H\cap \mathbb S^{2}$ under the stereographic projection $\Phi$.

Asked [here and I answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321443) agreeing with OP that the image is the circle $T: = \{|z-(1+i)|^2 = 3\}$, but now I ask:

> Q1. Is $(2)$ below wrong?
>
> $$\forall \ \text{planes} \ J, \exists \text{circle} \ C \in \mathbb S^2 : C = J \cap \mathbb S^2 \tag{2}$$

To clarify, compare that (2) is different from (1) below. We know that $$\forall \ \text{circles} \ C \in \mathbb S^2, \exists \ \text{plane} \ J : C = J \cap \mathbb S^2. \tag{1}$$

> Q2. Do I go wrong in attempting to disprove (2) as follows?

I think $(2)$ contradicts Exer 3.27: I observe that $E$, whose image is the circle $T$, is both

- the [intersection (WA)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2By-z%3D0,x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D1) of a plane and $\mathbb S^2$ and yet
- an [ellipse (WA)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%2B(x%2By)%5E2%3D1) --> Or is it? [Sphere-plane intersection seems to be circle (Wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_a_sphere#Sphere-plane_intersection).

If $(2)$ is true, then for $J=H, \exists C \in \mathbb S^2: C = H \cap \mathbb S^2 =: E ↯$.

> Q3. How is Exer 3.27 consistent with the succeeding Exer 3.28?

-

> (Exer 3.28) Prove that every circle in $\hat{\mathbb C}$ is the image of some circle in $\mathbb S^2$ under stereographic projection $\Phi$.

-

> I rephrase:
>   $$\forall \ R \in \hat{\mathbb C}, \exists C \in \mathbb S^2 : \Phi(C)=R$$

-

Now consider $T$, the circle in Exer 3.27 s.t. $\Phi(E)=T$.

It seems that by Exer 3.28, for $R= T, \exists C \in \mathbb S^2 : \Phi(C)=T$.

$$\therefore, \Phi(E) = \Phi(C) \ \text{while} \ E \ne C \ \text{, but} \ \Phi \ \text{is bijective ↯ ?}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Q1) I suspect some relationship is being illustrated. The 1st 2 coordinates in $[1,1,-1]$ are the centre of the circle $\Phi(E)$ while the norm of $[1,1,-1]$ s the radius of $\Phi(E)$.

(Q2) Yes if the planes intersect $\mathbb S^2$ or $\emptyset$ is considered a circle in $\mathbb S^2$.

(Q3), (Q4) E is not an ellipse. It is a [circle in 3D](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73242/140308) (see [here](http://www.asaurus.net/~buhr/academic/2004-1-ubc-math263/handouts/curve) too) parametrised as ([WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2,%20x%3Dsqrt(2%2F3)*cos(t),y%3D-sqrt(2%2F4)*sin(t)-sqrt(1%2F6)*cos(t),z%3D-sqrt(2%2F4)*sin(t)%2Bsqrt(1%2F6)*cos(t)))

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1(t)\\ 
x_2(t)\\ 
x_3(t)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{\frac 2 3} \cos[t]\\ 
-\sqrt{\frac 2 4} \sin[t] - \sqrt{\frac 2 {12}} \cos[t]\\ 
-\sqrt{\frac 2 4} \sin[t] + \sqrt{\frac 2 {12}} \cos[t]
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{\frac 1 3}\\ 
-\sqrt{\frac 1 {12}}\\ 
\sqrt{\frac 1 {12}}
\end{bmatrix}\sqrt{2}\cos(t)+   \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
-\sqrt{\frac 1 {4}}\\ 
-\sqrt{\frac 1 {4}}
\end{bmatrix}\sqrt{2}\sin(t)$$

Observe that while $x^2+y^2+xy=\frac12$ is an ellipse, $x^2+y^2+xy=\frac12 \wedge z= x+y$ is a circle.

Comment: I guess your major confusion was WA saying *ellipse* on the intersection. When you set $z=x+y$ into $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ you get indeed an ellipse, but this is the **projection** of the intersection onto $xy$-plane, i.e. all the coordinates $(x,y)$ that satisfy both equations.

Comment: @A.Γ. I was thinking projection but unable to express precisely. Thanks! Any idea for (Q1) please?

Comment: To see that all intersections are circles: 1. Intersection of a plane $z=\text{const}$ and the sphere is a circle (or empty set). 2. Any plane can be rotated to become $z=\text{const}$, and sphere is rotation invariant.

Comment: @A.Γ. cool. Thanks. How about Q1 please: what's the purpose of unit normal vector?

Comment: Is the image of $\Phi$ the plane $z=0$ or $z=-1$ (there are different conventions)?

Comment: @A.Γ. what do you mean? Exer 3.27 asks us about the unit normal vector before asking us to compute the image. I think we can compute the image without determining the unit normal vector. What is the purpose of the unit normal vector?

Comment: I do not see how knowing the normal may help finding the image. The exercise is pretty straightforward without the normal.

Comment: @A.Γ. Ayt thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As already verified, all intersections of a circle and plane are circles either [geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic)/[great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) or [small](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_a_sphere). I avoid symbols in the answer here.

If 2-parameter surface normal coincides with 1-parameter circle normal then the intersection is a great circle. The intersection is a geodesic.

From differential geometry standpoint $\psi$ is between arc and meridian. Cylindrical coordinates $(r,z)$ Clairaut constant derivative $\dfrac{d(r \sin \psi)}{dz}=0$ forms with respect to an arbitrary North-South polar axis.

If the 2-parameter surface  normal does not coincide with 1-parameter circle normal, but makes an angle $\gamma$ of relative latitude then the intersection is a small circle. Intersection is like a [parallel circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_latitude) but not an equator.

Clairaut constant derivative $\dfrac{d(r \sin \psi)}{dz}$ is a constant $ =\tan \gamma$ forms a *small* circle with respect to an arbitrary North-South polar axis.

In stereographic projection all non-equatorial sections of a plane passing through North pole of the sphere at angle $\gamma$ to North-South polar plane are small circles.

Comment: Narasimham, is [$E$ indeed](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2By-z%3D0,x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D1) an ellipse?

Comment: Narasimham, I posted an answer. How is it please?